# How do I measure fermentation rate?

Tags: data, measurement, fermentation

I'm doing a lab soon and I need to find a way to measure fermentation rate to a relatively high degree of accuracy without using a specialized sensor. It should ideally be done with easy to find tools at home or in the classroom.

Comment: http://www.freecontentweb.com/content/measuring-rate-alcohol-fermentation-yeast-cells Perhaps

Comment: @CMosychuk I'm not quite sure how there measuring it, I got lost when they said "its distance to the baseline water level." The difference of what to the baseline water level?

Comment: Your setup is essentially like [this](http://www.clayton.edu/portals/690/biology/lab-manual/ferment5.jpg). You have the fermentation occurring in one tube. The CO2 travels through tubing to another tube that was inverted with water in it, and the other end of the tubing fed through the bottom. The CO2 will force with water level in the inverted tube **down** so more CO2 = lower water level. If you take readings over time, you can measure the relative rate per unit time.

Comment: Here is a more [simple](http://mv.picse.net/fermentation/brewing/images/lab1.jpg) figure!

Comment: @CMosychuk I'm not sure I can do exactly that but I may be able to do a variation.